# UINavigationBar background - how to cover all sizes, resolutions and devices?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have the following code that works fine for setting a background image:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"navbar_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

My question is, for Xcode6, iOS8/9, iPhone 5, 6, 6+, iPad, etc, how do I make sure I cover all devices, widths and resolutions, to make sure that my background image always fills the navigation bar correctly?

I have seen other questions on SO and various other sites, but all have been 2-4 years old, and so don't mention or cover the latest device widths and resolutions.

I want to use a background image in the navigation bar, but I need to make sure it looks good on all possible devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is have three versions of your image in your asset catalogue. The first in the size you need the second twice the size and the third three times the size. Xcode will put the right image on the right device.

Alternatively you can just put a vectorial image and at complie time Xcode will generate the three images for you on the fly.

For the navigation bar you need separate images for portrait and landscape. You can write something like this:

```
UIImage *portraitImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_bar_portrait.png"];
UIImage *landscapeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_bar_landscape.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:portraitImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:landscapeImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Comment: I understand the 2x and 3x images. But if I make my original image 320px wide, how will that work for the wider iPhone6 / 6+, landscape orientation, etc?

Comment: if your 1x image is 320 then 2x image should be 640 and 3x should be  1280. as @Mika said its ios which take every image automatically